# Julia while loop slower than for loop?

Tags: performance, for-loop, while-loop, julia

I'm working with Julia 1.8.2 on the Advent of Code day 6 and noticed some strange performance difference between while and for loops.

I had written an implementation with a `for` loop, but realized that I did not need to go over each index, and I could skip indices in certain cases, but when I rewrote my code with a `while` loop it took ~10x as long to run. Both the `for` and the `while` loop code give the correct answer.
Then I added a small basic `while` vs `for` loop test to see if it was my code or the actual loops, and the results were even more dramatic. The `while` test took ~0.5s while the `for` test completed almost instantly.

My full code is given below, see [AoC day6](https://adventofcode.com/2022/day/6) for the data.

My question is why is the `while` loop so much slower? Does the Julia interpreter have a hard time optimizing `while` loops for some reason?

```
using BenchmarkTools

function parse_data()
    open(joinpath(dirname(@__FILE__), "data/day6.txt")) do f
        while !eof(f)
            line = readline(f)
            return line
        end
    end
end

function test_for(data)
    tot = 0
    for i = 1:length(data) * 100
        tot += 1
    end
    return tot
end

function test_while(data)
    tot = 0
    i = 1
    while i <= length(data) * 100
        tot += 1
        i += 1
    end
    return tot
end

function solve_problem_for(data)
    marker_length = 14
    for i = 1:length(data)
        repeat = false
        for (j, item) in enumerate(view(data, i:i+marker_length - 1))
            repeat = repeat || occursin(item, view(data, i + j:i + marker_length - 1))
            if repeat
                break
            end
        end
        if !repeat
            return i + marker_length - 1
        end
    end
end

function solve_problem_while(data)
    marker_length = 14
    i = 1
    while i <= length(data)
        repeat = false
        for (j, item) in enumerate(view(data, i:i+marker_length - 1))
            repeat = repeat || occursin(item, view(data, i + j:i + marker_length - 1))
            if repeat
                i += j - 1
                break
            end
        end
        if !repeat
            return i + marker_length - 1
        end
        i += 1
    end
end

function main()
    data = parse_data()
    @time sol = solve_problem_while(data)
    @time sol = solve_problem_while(data)
    println(sol)
    @time sol = test_while(data)
    @time sol = test_while(data)

    @time sol = solve_problem_for(data)
    @time sol = solve_problem_for(data)
    println(sol)
    @time sol = test_for(data)
    @time sol = test_for(data)
end


main()
```

Comment: In `while` each iteration you re-calculate `length(data) * 100`. Move that out of loop condition

Comment: If you want to benchmark something accurately, you should use `BenchmarkTools` and `@benchmark` to get better results

Comment: I get identical timings for `test_for` and `test_while`. Notice that both take just a couple of nanoseconds, regardless of the length of the input data. That is because the compiler recognizes that the output of this loop is N*(N+1)/2 and just skips the loop.

Comment: @Justinas Thank you, this recalculation caused the slow down. It seems like the compiler does not recognize that it won't change during the loop.

Comment: @WNed It's because condition is checked in each loop